# How to sort 300k+ lines of text into arrays by filename?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have 300k+ file names that I am trying to sort into an array based on the date in the file name.

My file list looks like:

```
D_VID-20060605_010GER
D_VID-20060605_013GWQR
D_VID-20060605_020JBRS
D_VID-20060605_023BJTUW
D_VID-20060605_030EQWJ
D_VID-20060606_033LLYE
D_VID-20060606_040SETW
D_VID-20060606_043JTYYE
D_VID-20060607_003FSE
D_VID-20060607_010UTJE
+306749 more
```

All of the files follow the exact same format as above.

I am trying to figure out how to automate the process of putting them all into an array sorted by date in the file name so that it will look like this:

```
y20060605 = new Array("Day","D_VID-20060605_010GER","D_VID-20060605_013GWQR","D_VID-20060605_020JBRS","D_VID-20060605_023BJTUW","D_VID-20060605_030EQWJ");

y20060606 = new Array("Day","D_VID-20060606_033LLYE","D_VID-20060606_040SETW","D_VID-20060606_043JTYYE");

y20060607 = new Array("Day","D_VID-20060607_003FSE","D_VID-20060607_010UTJE");
```

The reason why is because I am building a website where I can click dropdowns to select a year, month, and date and it'll show me the files available for the date selected. I have everything else built and running smoothly I just want to figure out how to sort the files into an array now without having to do 300k+ manually.

This is an example of my working code in case you need an idea of what exactly I'm working on: https://jsfiddle.net/zpj2mLr8/

Like I said, the code works it's just finding a way to sort the arrays so I don't have to spend years sorting them manually.

Comment: Sadly not, my text is already sorted by date and time. I just need it to be separated and put into different arrays based on the date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might have issues with the total number of entries. Might have to chunk it up. But the basic idea would be reduce.

```js
const data = `D_VID-20060605_010GER
D_VID-20060605_013GWQR
D_VID-20060605_020JBRS
D_VID-20060605_023BJTUW
D_VID-20060605_030EQWJ
D_VID-20060606_033LLYE
D_VID-20060606_040SETW
D_VID-20060606_043JTYYE
D_VID-20060607_003FSE
D_VID-20060607_010UTJE`

function getDate(x) {
  return x.match(/\d{8}/)[0]
}

var results = data.split(/\n/).reduce((o, item) => {
  var d = getDate(item)
  if (!o[d]) {
    o[d] = [item]
  } else {
    o[d].push(item)
  }
  return o
}, {})

//Object.values(results).forEach(arr => arr.sort())

console.log(results)
```

Comment: Not tested but I had something similar in mind. You can get the same result with a regular `for` loop if reduce functions are not your cup of tea !

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression to parse out the day, and create a map

```js
const files = `
D_VID-20060605_010GER
D_VID-20060605_013GWQR
D_VID-20060605_020JBRS
D_VID-20060605_023BJTUW
D_VID-20060605_030EQWJ
D_VID-20060606_033LLYE
D_VID-20060606_040SETW
D_VID-20060606_043JTYYE
D_VID-20060607_003FSE
D_VID-20060607_010UTJE
`;

const groups = new Map();


files.split("\n").filter(length => length).forEach(fileName => {

    const key = fileName.match(/\d{8}/).pop();
    
    if (groups.has(key)) {
        groups.set(key, groups.get(key).concat(fileName));
    } else {
        groups.set(key,[fileName]);
    }

});

for (var [day, filesInDay] of groups.entries()) {
  console.log(day, filesInDay);
}
```